# error 404 php website on iis7

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, http-status-code-404

We have a windows 2008 R2 server. On that server we have a website (twigo.nl). We have several sites under that domain (twigo.nl/umbraco , twigo.nl/imail and some others). Most of them are asp sites and work perfectly. However, recently i copied imail (php), because we need a Danish version. I named the copy twigo.nl/addressbook and it worked. After working in that folder for a while, I got a 404 not found. I asked my boss, and he said this problem has occured before, and that it always solves itself after a while, but he would like me to look into it and see if I can find where the problem lies. So I did some tests first.

I copied my (Danish) version and named it twigo.nl/addressbook2 --> worked perfectly.

I copied the original version and named it twigo.nl/addressbook3 --> worked perfectly.

I removed both originals and renamed the copies to the original names --> both worked again.

Especially that last test made no sense to me at all. I really hope someone can shed some light on this, because I have no idea what can cause something like this.

edit: I found out that after a while it indeed fixes itself, only to reappear again. I have tried sending a lot of requests when it worked but that didn't break it.

edit2: If anyone wants to take a closer look at the application, it can be downloaded here: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/302807/R518HiPFG2dTH1mT/addressbook.rar. I have filtered out the database connection, but everything else is there. (also wouldn't mind if someone copied parts of it for himself ;))

edit3: Link to the live application (currently broken) http://twigo.nl/addressbook/index.php?token=7eb92889-8c87-4b5c-a144-68b761954dea

edit4: The token passed in the url is a securitytoken in the database, it seems that the token is changed every now and then. Does anyone have any idea where to look for something like that? I need to find out what changes that token, and see if I can disable it or adapt my application to work with the constant changing.

Comment: I would like to see some code or "something". Perhaps directory structure? (In a picture?) Don't know how someone  could actually error search this without more information.

Comment: @OlofEdler http://i40.tinypic.com/1zxxdth.png, this is the directory structure. I wouldn't know where to start with the code, there are 560 files spread across 40 folders :s. This would've been a lot easier if I had made this app myself.

Comment: Did you look at IIS logs and find something interesting?

Comment: @SalmanA I did look, but i didn't find anything related :(

Comment: You should have found 404 errors recorded in the logs along with time, requested URL and other information.

Comment: @SalmanA I have found some things like: 
2012-01-17 08:39:47 109.109.121.12 GET /addressbook - 80 - 109.109.121.12 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 301 0 0 2
2012-01-17 08:39:47 109.109.121.12 GET /addressbook/ - 80 - 109.109.121.12 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 200 0 0 61. But it doesn't mean anything to me :(

Comment: Look at the fourth column from end, it contains the http status code (301 and 200 respectively). Look at rows that contain 404 in that column, note down the URL (GET /whatever) and see if that file actually exist.

Comment: @SalmanA all files exist, else it wouldn't work in the first place. The problem is it stops working after a while. But I have found that the token in the url is checked in the database, and the token in the database changes sometimes. I think that is the problem.